# How to copy text between 2 html tags?

Tags: html, linux, bash

I want to copy all the text in a website between tags:

> `<p> and </p>`

using bash. 
Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use an HTML parser.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Comment: Do you want to get the text out of the HTML page or do you want to make a html page by filling the space between `<p>` and `</p>` in your template html page with some other string?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above states: don't even try. There is no reliable way to parse HTML with Bash internals.
But when you're using a shell you may as well use third-party command line tools such as [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) which are built for HTML parsing on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an HTML parser is a better choice.  But if you are just trying to grab the text in between the first set of P tags quickly, you can use Perl:

```
perl -n0e 'if (/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/s) { print $1; }'
```

For example:

```
echo "
<p>A test
here
today</p>
<p>whatever</p>
" | perl -n0e 'if (/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/s) { print $1; }'
```

This will output:

```
A test
here
today
```